# Convert multiple float values into string using dtostrf

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, c-strings

I am struggling with the code below

```
float txValue = 123.45678f;

char txString1[6],txString2[6],txString[25];
dtostrf(txValue, 5, 2, txString1);
dtostrf(txValue+1, 5, 2, txString2);

Serial.print(txString1);
Serial.print("\n");
```

The output is "123.45124.45".

It is strange because the second `dtostrf` function corrected `txString1`. I assume the problem comes from that the `dtostrf` function outputs the string to the pointer of `txString1`.

Can anyone help me get `txString1` equal to "123.45" and `txString2` equal to "124.45"?

Comment: c-strings always need an additional character for the nul terminator. Increase the size of the char array.

Comment: note that second parameter is `width` (=5) which is [minimum field width of the output string](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html). So result can be longer then 5, in fact result has length 6, adding terminating zero and you have buffer overflow.